# Creating multiple sql databases of the same structure using Peewee

Tags: python, python-3.x, peewee

I am looking to create 26 separate sql databases, each with the same structure. (i.e. one for each letter of the alphabet), ideally which i can access from a dictionary or similar [i.e. to access the database corresponding to the letter `a` with `database["a"]` ].

I currently have the following code, which generates one sql database (in this case for the letter a) using peewee.

```
from peewee import *
database_location_a = "C:\\database\\a.db"
data_sql_a= SqliteDatabase(database_location_a, threadlocals=True, pragmas=(("synchronous", "off"),))           

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = data_sql_a

class main_table(BaseModel):
    file_name = CharField(primary_key = True)
    year = CharField()

data_sql_a.connect()    
data_sql_a.create_tables([main_table])
```

There are parts of this code i can easily loop over (e.g. i can easily create a dictionary of file locations). However, where i am stuck is that given the location is coded into the class `Basemodel`, how do i loop over that [i.e. do i need 26 separate classes, and if so, can i create that without needing to copy/paste the class 26 times]? And similarly, given `main_table` uses `BaseModel`, would i need 26 separate instances of that class as well?

I may well be going about this the wrong way, but want to know what approach could i take to adapt this code to create multiple files, without needing to copy/paste it multiple times?

Comment: Could you not add a parameter to the `BaseModel` for a database object?

Comment: @cricket_007 Could you possible elaborate - i should probably have noted that i have not used classes in Python much before, so i suspect there is a very simple solution .

Comment: Nevermind, I don't know peewee. I think what you want is a [database proxy](https://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/database.html#dynamically-defining-a-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get a running solution using the peewee [database proxy object](https://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/database.html#dynamically-defining-a-database).

```
from peewee import *
database_proxy = Proxy()

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database_proxy  # Use proxy for our DB.

class main_table(BaseModel):
    file_name = CharField(primary_key = True)
    year = CharField()

import string
db_names = string.ascii_lowercase
# print(db_names) # abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

'''
Loop over all the characters in the string and create databases in the current folder of this script
'''
for db_name in db_names:
    database = SqliteDatabase('{}.db'.format(db_name), threadlocals=True, pragmas=(("synchronous", "off"),))
    database_proxy.initialize(database)
    database_proxy.connect()
    database_proxy.create_tables([main_table])
```

According to the [Proxy documentation](https://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Proxy.initialize), you can just use that `database_proxy` variable as you normally would for the `database` object after calling `database_proxy.initialize(database)`. For example, the `connect()` and `create_tables()` are actually being called on `database` through `database_proxy`.